# Regular expression filename matching

Tags: php, regex, drupal-7

I am writing a PHP function in Drupal to detect duplicate file uploads and attempting to compare the uploaded filename to previously uploaded files.

I have example files of:

```
trees-nature_0.jpg
trees-nature_1.jpg
trees-nature0.jpg
trees-nature.jpg
```

I am trying to match all of them all using the following code:

```
file_scan_directory('image/uploads', "/trees-nature[*]?.jpg/");
```

However, all I get back is **trees-nature.jpg**.

I would appreciate some correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
file_scan_directory('image/uploads', '/trees-nature(.*?)\.jpg/');
```

> Correction:

- `[ ]` cannot be used as parentheses.. it has special meaning in regex
- `*` is not wildcard in regex.. you have to use `.*`
- `.` also has special meaning here (any character) you need to escape it

Comment: Much better: `.*?` instead of: `(.*)?`

Comment: They both worked but why not use (.*) ? It seems neater - atleast

Comment: both are same but `(.*)?` takes more steps compared to `(.*?)` to match same string.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is not correct. use:

```
file_scan_directory('image/uploads', '/trees-nature.*?\.jpg/');
```